# Как сделать пагинацию в вордпресс при одинаковом slug страницы с лентой постов и slug поста?

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть тип постов со слагом `blog`, то есть посты будут открываться по url:

`domain.com/blog/post-name`

Все эти посты выводятся на странице с таким вот url:

`domain.com/blog`

Если пытаться делать пагинацию, то начинаются проблемы, на второй странице контента не будет:

`domain.com/blog/page/2`

Если поменять slug у страницы со списком записей или slug у типа записей, то все будет нормально работать. Но мне важно, чтобы slug бы именно такой. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: У вас проблема в теме или плагинах. Смените тему на стандартную, отключите плагины, проверьте. Посмотрите на мой тестовый сайт - все работает: http://test.kagg.eu/blog/

Comment: У меня нет плагинов. А по ссылке доступ закрыт.

Comment: Да, закрывал доступ для некоторых категорий, в качестве иллюстрации к одному ответа здесь. Да и забыл. Открыл.

Comment: Посмотрел. У вас не так работает, как нужно. У вас url записи `domain.com/post-name`, а нужно `domain.com/blog/post-name`.

Comment: Вы тему меняли на стандартную?

Comment: Если я поменяю тему на стандартную, то у меня пропадет мой кастомный тип записи.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79663/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-dmitryshishkin).